# OAuth2 implementation error. The third party sent an invalid redirect URI

Tags: vb.net, oauth-2.0, webforms

I want to implement Oauth in my vb.net web form application. I use response.redirect to go to the url containing all information like client id,secret,redirect url etc. My redirect url is "http://localhost:50689/NetDocsTokenStatus.aspx" .
The url redirects me to the net documents website where I input my username and password. And then I get the following error: An external application attempted to access your account, but the request was not valid: The third party sent an invalid redirect URI.

But if I change my redirect uri to https://localhost, it shows me a screen to allow / deny permissions. If I allow it fails to redirect me saying localhost refused connection. But I see the auth code in the url.

Kindly guide.

On click of the button, I redirect to the NetDocs vault url with the required parameters as below:

```
Protected Sub btnGenerateTokens_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim _redirectURI = "http://localhost:50689/NetDocsTokenStatus.aspx" 
        Response.Redirect(_baseLoginUrl + "?client_id=" + _clientID + "&scope=" + _scope + "&response_type=" + _responseType + "&redirect_uri=" + _redirectURI + "&ie7warn=N")

    End Sub
```

In the same page NetDocstokenStatus.aspx

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Request.Params("code") IsNot Nothing Then
            query = Request.Params("code")
        End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: *I guess* you are not using IIS. Use IIS and some domain name other than "localhost", put it in the hosts file, and you can stick to the normal port of 80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS. You really don't need the hassle of dealing with non-standard port numbers. ICBW.

Comment: I am using IIS Express.

Comment: Try using IIS, then the the port numbers are stable.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I changed my web app properties to enable SSL and use port no 443. I could redirect back to https://localhost/ but not to the page I wanted, but I did get the auth code back on my default.aspx page and then redirected back to the page where I need the auth code.